# Why is Jacobi Identity equivalent to holonomy of system?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras, differential-equations, integrable-systems

Or equivalently, why is jacobi identity equivalent to integrability of system? How do I understand it intuitively? Thanks.

Comment: Could you say more explicitly what you mean by the Jacobi identity and the holonomy of system?

Comment: Once we make sense of the intended question, it's answered by Chapter II.3 of Baez-Muniain's book *"Gauge fields, knots, and gravity"*.

Comment: not an answer, but reference to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113766/jacobi-identity-intuitive-explanation